# mysql select one of two fields where one of them equal a value

Tags: mysql, database, relational-database

I have two tables "users" and "relations", i want to select the relations of all users.

```
table relations
user1 user2
1     2
1     3
5     1
```

in above example table, it holds the ids are related to users table.

i want to select all relations for user id 1 and join his friend's names for example and should expect return

```
id   name
2    demo friends1
3    demo friends2
5    demo friends3
```

so what i tried:-

```
Select (case user1='1' then r.user2 else r.user1 end) as id,u.name from relations r
join users u on u.id = (case r.user1='1' then r.user2 else r.user1 end)
where (user1 = 1 or user2= 2);
```

this is close to what i want i guess. can some one clearify to me what i'm doing wrong ?
and is there a better way to do it ?

Comment: `SELECT u2.id, u2.name FROM users u1 JOIN relations ON (u1.id = user1) JOIN u2 ON (user2 = u2.id) WHERE u1 = 1`.  I may not fully understand what you're trying to do

Answer (score 0):

Given your structure, one way to do it is:

```
SELECT users.id, users.name
FROM relations
INNER JOIN users ON relations.user2 = users.id
WHERE relations.user1 = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT users.id, users.name
FROM relations
INNER JOIN users ON relations.user1 = users.id
WHERE relations.user2 = 1
```

---

This does assume you are being diligent to not include duplicate rows. One way to make sure of this is to establish a constraint that `user1` should always be less than `user2`, and you have a composite unique key (`user1`, `user2`) - which would most likely be your PK.

In this case, the data stored would change to the following:

```
user1 user2
1     2
1     3
1     5
```

---

For completeness in understanding, there are other ways to accomplish what you desire. This query is almost identical to the first one except that the union is taken in the derived table rather than in the outermost layer. A good query optimizer may recognize the two as the same though:

```
SELECT users.id, users.name
FROM users
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT user1 AS id FROM relations WHERE user2 = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT user2 AS id FROM relations WHERE user1 = 1
) friends ON users.id = friends.id
```

Or a really ugly query like the following, which resembles your attempt. This will undoubtedly be slower and I would not recommend it (the `CASE` and `OR` are extra processing steps that will slow things down and possibly invalidate the use of indexes):

```
SELECT users.id, users.name
FROM users
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT CASE WHEN user1 = 1 THEN user2 ELSE user1 END AS id
    FROM relations
    WHERE user1 = 1 OR user2 = 1
) friends ON users.id = friends.id
```

You can look at the `EXPLAIN` results of these queries and determine which is the most optimal.

Answer (score 0):

You can do in this way also

```
SELECT *  FROM `users` WHERE id IN (SELECT user1 FROM relations WHERE user2='1')
OR
id IN(SELECT user2 FROM relations WHERE user1='1')
```

id 1 can be in `user1` or `user2` it will fetch all the related users

[**HERE IS YOUR FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/94335/1)